# subprocess.popen() stderr redirection with pipes / fails

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run a process which may produce a lot of output for up to timeout seconds, capturing the `stdout`/`stderr`. Using `capture()` and `PIPE` as `stdout`/`stderr` is prone to deadlocking according to the [documentation for `subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Now, I'm using `poll()` anyways -- because I want to be able to kill the process after the timeout -- but I still don't know how to avoid the deadlock using PIPE. How do I do that?

Currently I'm just working around by creating tempfiles:

```
#because of the shitty api, this has to be a file, because std.PIPE is prone to deadlocking with a lot of output, and I can't figure out what to do about it
out, outfile = tempfile.mkstemp()
err, errfile = tempfile.mkstemp()

now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M, %Ss')
print "Running '" + exe + "' with a timeout of ", timeout , "s., starting at ", now
p = subprocess.Popen(args = exe,
                     stdout = out,
                     #for some reason, err isn't working if the process is killed by the kernel for, say, using too much memory.
                     stderr = err,
                     cwd = dir)

start = time.time()

# take care of infinite loops
sleepDuration = 0.25
time.sleep(0.1)
lastPrintedDuration = 0
duration = 0
while p.poll() is None:
    duration = time.time() - start
    if duration > lastPrintedDuration + 1:
        lastPrintedDuration += 1
        #print '.',
        sys.stdout.flush()
    if duration >= timeout:
        p.kill()
        raise Exception("Killed after " + str(duration) + "s.")
    time.sleep(sleepDuration)

if p.returncode is not 0:
    with open(errfile, 'r') as f:
        e = f.read()
        #fix empty error messages
        if e == '':
            e = 'Program crashed, or was killed by kernel.'
        f.close()

    os.close(out)
    os.close(err)
    os.unlink(outfile)
    os.unlink(errfile)
    print "Error after " + str(duration) + 's: ',
    print "'" + e + "'"
    raw_input('test')
    raise Exception(e)
else:
    print "completed in " + str(duration) + 's.'

os.close(out)
os.close(err)
os.unlink(outfile)
os.unlink(errfile)
```

But even this **fails to capture errors** if the process is killed by, say, the kernel (out of memory, etc.).

What's the ideal solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using files for the output, go back to using pipes but use the [fcntl](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html) module to put `p.stdout` and `p.stderr` into non-blocking mode.  This will cause `p.stdout.read()` and `p.stderr.read()` to return whatever data is available or raise an `IOError` if there is no data, instead of blocking:

```
import fcntl, os

p = subprocess.Popen(args = exe,
                     stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                     cwd = dir)
fcntl.fcntl(p.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
fcntl.fcntl(p.stderr.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)

outdata, errdata = '', ''
while p.poll() is None:
    try:
        outdata += p.stdout.read()
    except IOError:
        pass
    try:
        errdata += p.stderr.read()
    except IOError:
        pass
    time.sleep(sleepDuration)
```

As glglgl pointed out in comments, you should do some additional checking in the `except IOError` clause to make sure that it is not actually a real error.

Comment: That's far too simple. Not every `IOError` should be ignored, just the `EAGAIN` ones.

Comment: Is the fcntl call really necessary? What would happen without that call?

Comment: @hrehfeld - The `read()` call would block, either until the process finishes or indefinitely (depending on buffering), so you wouldn't have the ability to kill your process after a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with non-blocking mode is that you end up busy-waiting for I/O. The more conventional approach is to use one of the [select](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) calls. Even if you have only one file descriptor to read/write, you can stick your desired timeout on it, so you regain control after the specified interval with no further I/O.